# Distinguish between key press and release of MIDI piano input

Tags: java, release, midi, piano

I am about to make a little program for a school project that is supposed to recognize the chords that are being played via a MIDI piano input (that's just one part of it).

At the moment I got so far that for each press and each release of a key on the midi keyboard I get an object of the class `ShortMessage`.

My question: How do I figure out if the key has been pressed or released?
In each case, press and release, the static variable `NOTE_OFF` does contain the value 128, the variable `NOTE_ON` the value 144.

I don't get how this is supposed to tell me if the key has been pressed or released. Any idea? Am I missing a fundamental thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"In each case (press and release) the static variable NOTE_OFF does contain the value 128"* What static variable?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Just FWIW, a ***very*** long time ago (the last time I dealt with MIDI was > 20 years ago), some instruments never sent "Note Off" events at all. They sent "Note On" events with a velocity of 0. Very confusing.

Comment: Isn't the status field (accessible through the `getStatus()` method inherited from `MidiMessage`) the one that may contain `NOTE_ON` / `NOTE_OFF` ? I'm pretty sure it is, but can't test it.

Answer (score 1):

`NOTE_ON` and `NOTE_OFF` are just constants; you compare the message's actual command value (`getCommand()`) with them.

Please note that a note-on message with a velocity (`getData2()`) of zero must be interpreted as a note-off message.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use the [JFugue](http://www.JFugue.org) library for your application.

```
// You'll need some try/catches around this block. This is traditional Java Midi code.
MidiDevice.Info[] infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
MidiDevice device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(infos[0]); // You'll have to get the right device for your MIDI controller. 

// Here comes the JFugue code
MusicTransmitterToParserListener m = new MusicTransmitterToParserListener(device);
m.addParserListener(new ChordParserListener());

// Choose either this option:
m.startListening();
...do stuff...
m.stopListening();

// Or choose this option:
m.listenForMillis(5000); // Listen for 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)


public ChordParserListener extends ParserListenerAdapter {
    List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>;

    @Override public void onNotePressed(Note note) {
        notes.add(note);
        // Go through your list and see if you have a chord
    }
    @Override public void onNoteReleased(Note note) {
        // Remove the note from the list, might not be as easy as notes.remove(note)
    }
}
```

JFugue also has a [Chord](http://www.jfugue.org/doc/index.html) class that you might find useful -- especially the method that returns a Chord given an array of Notes... it's called `Chord.fromNotes(Note[] notes)` -- unless that takes away the challenge that you're hoping to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "question" and tried the suggested from Aaron's comment:

> Isn't the status field (accessible through the getStatus() method
>   inherited from MidiMessage) the one that may contain NOTE_ON /
>   NOTE_OFF ? I'm pretty sure it is, but can't test it.

It works just fine!. Thank you Poster and Aaron!.

```
if( sm.getStatus() == sm.NOTE_ON )
{
   piano-key-down.
}
```